# What visa do I need to travel to the United States (Texas)

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens

I'm planning on traveling to **Texas (El Paso)** in October 2014. This will be my first time traveling alone with no parents.

I do not fully understand visas and their needs. This trip is purely for **pleasure** and I'll be returning in **14 days**...

I read that I may be eligible for a **visa waiver program**. Since I'm a **UK Citizen** (Born and Bred) and have *no criminal convictions* and staying less than 90 days. I have (waiting for) a passport that will have an electronic chip.

Comment: How will you be traveling?  Flying, I presume?  Or will you be crossing by land from Mexico, for instance?

Comment: You've got it easy. Do the ESTA, book your flight, and bring your passport.

Comment: I found a visa waver wizard on the us embasies website. Looks like all i need is a ESTA like @pnuts said. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US the tourist visa is called [B1/B2 visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html)

Generally speaking you should be able to travel under the US Visa Waiver Program for which [UK Citizens are eligible](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#vwp2).

In order to use the Visa Waiver Program you will need to apply for [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/).  This however restricts you to arriving on so called [Signatory Carriers](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/87163.pdf) to be eligible for VWP.

Otherwise you will need to apply for a B1/B2 visa at the closes US Consulate which has [a Visa Wizard](http://london.usembassy.gov/root/visa-wizard/pages/index.html) to make a determination on what you will need to apply for easier.

Comment: A couple of nitpicks: Sometimes tourists are issued B-2 visas instead of B-1/B-2.  A VWP traveler need not arrive on a signatory carrier if crossing by land from Canada or Mexico, even if they have ESTA.